# Error when creating private pod using paypal

Tags: paypal, cocoapods

Im getting this error when try to push the repo to pod.

- ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (The 'Pods' target has transitive dependencies that include static binaries: (/private/var/folders/_5/s6k8gtbd1mj24s4wbz3j1q_00000gn/T/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/PayPal-iOS-SDK/PayPalMobile/libPayPalMobile.a)) during validation.

any one have idea plz